# Sum each n elements and store in another vector matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, sum

I have the following function:

```
b = [-1 1];
m = b(randi(length(b),1,nsimul*n));
```

Is there a way to do sum to every n elements and store in another vector?

Example:

```
b = [-1 1];
m = b(randi(length(b),1,5*2));
m
m =
        1    -1     1    -1     1    -1    -1     1     1    -1
A(1) = m(1) + m(2);
A(2) = m(3) + m(4);
A(3) = m(5) + m(6);
A(4) = m(7) + m(8);
A(5) = m(9) + m(10);
A
A = 
        0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: just reshape and sum the right dimension

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`vec2mat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/vec2mat.html) to reshape you vector to a matrix of the dimension that fits the # of elements you want to sum on, and the you just need to sum the right dimension.
[`vec2mat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/vec2mat.html) is nice because it will pad with zeros the reminder of the 1D vector in case you choose a # of elements that is incommensurate with a NxM matrix, For example:

```
vec2mat(m,2)

ans =

 1    -1
 1    -1
 1    -1
-1     1
 1    -1
```

more generally, let's call `n_elements` the # of elements you want to sum on, then:

```
 n_elements=2;
 a=sum(vec2mat(m,n_elements),2)
```

But if the 1D vector and the # of elements is always commensurate and no padding is needed you can use the good old `reshape`, as mentioned in the comments below...

Comment: Seems inefficient, `vec2mat` writes the data row-wise, meaning it needs to copy it. `reshape` would do the same thing but without copying the data: `sum(reshape(m,n_elements,[]))` (assuming no padding is needed).

Comment: padding is the entire point using it. and the question didn't ask for efficiency.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet should provide what you are looking for:

```
% Define the parameters...
nsimul = 5;
n = 2;
b = [-1 1];

% Compute the final result...
m = b(randi(length(b),1,nsimul*n));
k = sum(reshape(m,n,[]).',2);
```

Given, for example, the vector:

```
m = [-1 -1  1  1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1]
```

The final result `s` would be:

```
s = [-2  2 -2  0  2]
```

with the intermediate result `k` given by the [reshape](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) function equal to:

```
k = [
 -1  -1
  1   1
 -1  -1
 -1   1
  1   1
]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you all for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. If this implementation solves your problems, please, kindly consider marking it as accepted.